# I am not being able to create an ionic project with react

Tags: ionic-framework

When i use this in my terminal

ionic start my-app tabs --type=react

this happend:

[ERROR] react is not a valid project type.

```
    Please choose a different --type. Use ionic start --list to list all
    available starter templates.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need to install the correct tools

`npm install -g @ionic/cli native-run cordova-res`

Why not try out official docs tutorial??
https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app